# get() unable to find POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to build ajax comments in my django app. Comments are written in a TextField(), which have a name="comments_text" and class="comment_text. So to fetch the entered text I tried `ajax_comment = request.POST.get('comment_text')`. However this returned `None` for some reason. Here's my code:

**models.py**

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.IntegerField()
    parent_id = models.IntegerField()
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments

        fields = [
            'comment_text'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def article(request, category, id):

    ...

    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

    ajax_comment = request.POST.get('comment_text')
    print(ajax_comment) #returns None

    if request.is_ajax(): #True
        if comment.is_valid(): # True
            ajax_comment = request.POST.get('comment_text')
            print(ajax_comment) #returns None
            return HttpResponse('Something')

    context = {
        'comment': comment,
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

**template**

```
<div class="commentsContainer">

    <form action="" class="comment_form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment.comment_text|add_class:"comment_text" }}
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="comment_submit">
    </form>
    <div class="comment_div">
        <h3>Username1</h3>
        <p>Something</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**base.js**

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    console.log(url); // this works fine

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        text: $('.comment_text').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
},
    success: function(text) {
        $('.comment_div').append("<div class='comment_div'><h3>username</h3><p>" + text + "</p></div>");
        console.log(text); // text=something&csrfmiddlewaretoken=sWJashvQgbKG9hM0imiFTjj3EQrCP5qRfq60XraoQK1SULlPumJonyMktt9DllEC
    }
})


});
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see `'comment_text'` in JavaScript. You send comment text as `'text'` - see `data: { text: ... }`

Comment: Thankyou it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Ajax request header in the **Network** tab of browser. It could be either not passing the parameter `'text'` or passing `text = ''`
[image: chrome_network_tab]

In either of cases, the response would be `none`.

Probably reason is that during ajax request `text: $('.comment_text').val(),` is not getting desired value (because .`comment_text` class doesnt exist; did Django template add the class attribute?). Thereby ***Django View*** is not receiving the `text` value to print on console.

Also, there is inconsitency between your ajax request and Django View.

**views.py**

```
ajax_comment = request.POST.get('comment_text')
```

**base.js**

```
data: {
        text: $('.comment_text').val(),
```

**base.js - *revised***

```
data: {
        comment_text: $('.comment_text').val(),
```